# clearCanvas() with draggable layers

Tags: jquery, canvas, draggable, jcanvas, clearcanvas

When I add normal objects or layers to the canvas (using [jCanvas](http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/)) I'm able to clear the canvas using the `clearCanvas()` function.

But when I make my layers draggable the `clearCanvas()` function does not seem to work. It does clear the canvas when I click the button, but as soon as the mouse hovers the canvas again the removed content gets added again. What am I doing wrong here?

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6MKBC/)

```
$('canvas').drawArc({
    fillStyle: 'black',
    x: 100, y: 100,
    radius: 50,
    draggable: true, // uncomment this and Clear canvas works.
    layer: true,
});

$('#clear').click(function(){
    $('canvas').clearCanvas();
});
```

Comment: I could not answer my own question because I did not have enough reputation yet. Only option was to edit my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>*[UPDATE by Mirko](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/22766618/2) (here you are sir)*</sub>

[Caleb Evans](http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/) gave me the solution for my issue:

The `clearCanvas()` method was only intended to be used with non-layer (static) drawings. Whenever you have at least one jCanvas layer for your canvas, `clearCanvas()` becomes inapplicable.

if you wish to remove a layer completely (assuming you will never need it again), use the `removeLayer()` method.

```
$('#clear').click(function(){
    $('canvas').removeLayers();
    $('canvas').drawLayers();
});
```

Comment: nicolallias, in a case like this, the etiquette is making your answer *Community Wiki* so you don't get reputation for an answer that is not yours.